# Combining IIf statement in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Been trying, without success to include an IIf statement in the query below.

The query below counts how many matches a player has one. This across all courts.
Now I want to count the winning and losing match per player but also depending on the surface. "Hard" in this example.

Tried everything but keep getting errors.

```
SELECT [%$##@_Alias].Player, Sum([%$##@_Alias].Won) AS SumOfWon, Sum([%$##@_Alias].Lost) AS SumOfLost INTO Mastertemp
FROM (SELECT First([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Winner]) AS Player,
    Count([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Winner]) AS Won,
    0 AS Lost
    FROM [Master Data Results 2013 - 2016]
    GROUP BY [Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Winner]
    HAVING (((Count([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Winner])) > 0))

    UNION

    SELECT First([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Loser]) AS Player,
    0 as Won,
    Count([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Loser]) AS Lost
    FROM [Master Data Results 2013 - 2016]
    GROUP BY [Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Loser]
    HAVING (((Count([Master Data Results 2013 - 2016].[Loser])) > 0))
)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
GROUP BY [%$##@_Alias].Player;
```

Comment: @Parfait, but how can I do the count when the surface is "hard"? Now it counts everything on all surfaces, I want to count only hard court

Comment: Add that as a `WHERE` condition in your union selects.